# Is there any api present to get recently played songs in BeatsMusic?

Tags: java, android, beatsmusic

i could find APIs to see tracks from My Playlist and My Library but couldn't find APIs to play most played or recently played songs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening history is not yet available on the public API.